# determine size of objects that are transferred from server side to client side by web service .net in debug mode

Tags: c#, .net, performance, profiling, server-side

I want to measure the size of the object in kb that I get from my server side to the client side
(I use two servers one that host the asp.net application and the other one that hosts my server side code and the database) when I debug the code.

I don't how to determine what is the size that been transferred from the server side to the client side through the web service in the debug mode.

Which tools I can use? Or is there a solution that exists in Visual Studio in debug mode that I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: What technology do you use? WCF? WebClient?

Comment: I tried it, but didnt get a good result. I am senden data in bulk and fear that i reach the max message size for some of the data objects. The only way i found is to serialize the Messages twice or just intercept the messages (if http with fiddler2)

Comment: I use web service (soap)